# Передать название таблицы через параметер ADO.NET

Tags: ado.net, sql

Почему этот код выбрасывает исключение: Must declare the table variable "@tablename".

```
static public Object[,] GetTable(string tableName)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new   SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Satisfies;Integrated Security=SSPI");
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from @tablename", connection);
    var param = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tablename", tableName);

    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); //Throws exception here

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А разве можно передавать в качестве параметра названия таблицы ? Параметрезированый запрос передает параметры для WHERE например. Наверное надо делать так

String sql = "select * from " + tableName;
new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

Comment: да, но я не хотел через конкатенацию строк делать так как будет уязвимость sql injection

Comment: Ну это уже вопрос другой, безопасность наверное вам нужно в другом месте продумывать.

Comment: Отделять слои работа с БД и контролер форм например. Или что у вас я не знаю. Конектиться к БД из контролера не очень хорошо.

Comment: Да в моем случае это не критично, я просто для общего развития интересуюсь есть ли возможность избежать конкатенации строк так как я читал что это плохой стиль. Но в общем вы ответили на мой вопрос - передавать в качестве параметра название таблицы невозможно.)